# How to emit delayed values after Subject emits?

Tags: rxjs

I have a BehavoirSubject and whenever it emits I would like to emit  an other delayed value.
Is there an elegant way to implement it using rxjs operators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example like this:

```
const s = new BehavoirSubject();

const delayed$ = s.pipe(
  switchMap(v => merge(
    of(v),
    of(v).pipe(delay(XYZ))
  ))
);
```

Maybe you want to use `switchMap` instead of `mergeMap`.